# How do I render form from <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, razorpay

```html
<form>
  <script 
     src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js" 
     data-payment_button_id="pl_GspBivPLMSWeEC"
     async> 
  </script>
</form>
```

How do I render this in React? It works good on normal HTML.

On render it must show me a Pay Button like this:

[image: Razorpay ‘Pay Now’ button]

React is not able to render this. How do I fix this?

After clicking on that form it must show a payment screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const form = document.createElement("form");
const script = document.createElement("script");

script.src = "https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js";
script.setAttribute("data-payment_button_id", "pl_GspBivPLMSWeEC");
script.async = true;

form.appendChild(script);
document.body.appendChild(form);

return () => {
  document.body.removeChild(form);
};}, []);
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-glade-sbblb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello iFrame</h1>

      <iframe
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        style={{ overflow: "hidden", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
        height="100%"
        title={"test"}
        srcdoc="
      <form>
        <script 
          src='https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js'
          data-payment_button_id='pl_GspBivPLMSWeEC'
          async> 
        </script>
      </form>
      "
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-albattani-up6je?file=/src/App.js:0-550)